# Travis CI not recognizing API key environment variables

Tags: python, heroku, environment-variables, travis-ci

I am trying to store API keys (two of them) in two encrypted environment variables for Travis and it says that they're imported, then doesn't recognize them. The two variables are `TWILIO_TOKEN` and `TWILIO_ACCT`. I also have these stored in a `.env` variable for Heroku. I have tried using the dashboard -> settings -> Environment Variables on Travis-ci.org (public repository), as well as `travis encrypt TWILIO_ACCT=<key> --add env.matrix` (two of these). What's happening?

Log:

```
Using worker: worker-linux-docker-dce1945a.prod.travis-ci.org:travis-linux-2

Build system information
Build language: python
Build group: stable
Build dist: precise
Build image provisioning date and time
Thu Feb  5 15:09:33 UTC 2015
Operating System Details
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 12.04.5 LTS
Release:    12.04
Codename:   precise
Linux Version
3.13.0-29-generic
Cookbooks Version
a68419e https://github.com/travis-ci/travis-cookbooks/tree/a68419e
GCC version
gcc (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.3-1ubuntu5) 4.6.3
Copyright (C) 2011 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

LLVM version
clang version 3.4 (tags/RELEASE_34/final)
Target: x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix
Pre-installed Ruby versions
ruby-1.9.3-p551
Pre-installed Node.js versions
v0.10.36
Pre-installed Go versions
1.4.1
Redis version
redis-server 2.8.19
riak version
2.0.2
MongoDB version
MongoDB 2.4.12
CouchDB version
couchdb 1.6.1
Neo4j version
1.9.4
RabbitMQ Version
3.4.3
ElasticSearch version
1.4.0
Installed Sphinx versions
2.0.10
2.1.9
2.2.6
Default Sphinx version
2.2.6
Installed Firefox version
firefox 31.0esr
PhantomJS version
1.9.8
ant -version
Apache Ant(TM) version 1.8.2 compiled on December 3 2011
mvn -version
Apache Maven 3.2.5 (12a6b3acb947671f09b81f49094c53f426d8cea1; 2014-12-14T17:29:23+00:00)
Maven home: /usr/local/maven
Java version: 1.7.0_76, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/jre
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: ANSI_X3.4-1968
OS name: "linux", version: "3.13.0-29-generic", arch: "amd64", family: "unix"

$ export DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive
W: Size of file /var/lib/apt/lists/us.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_precise-backports_multiverse_source_Sources.gz is not what the server reported 5886 5888
W: Size of file /var/lib/apt/lists/ppa.launchpad.net_ubuntugis_ppa_ubuntu_dists_precise_main_binary-amd64_Packages.gz is not what the server reported 36669 36677
W: Size of file /var/lib/apt/lists/ppa.launchpad.net_ubuntugis_ppa_ubuntu_dists_precise_main_binary-i386_Packages.gz is not what the server reported 36729 36733
Reading package lists...
Building dependency tree...
Reading state information...
The following extra packages will be installed:
  libc-bin libc-dev-bin libc6-dev
Suggested packages:
  glibc-doc
The following packages will be upgraded:
  libc-bin libc-dev-bin libc6 libc6-dev
4 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 236 not upgraded.
Need to get 8,840 kB of archives.
After this operation, 14.3 kB disk space will be freed.
Get:1 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates/main libc6-dev amd64 2.15-0ubuntu10.15 [2,943 kB]
Get:2 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates/main libc-dev-bin amd64 2.15-0ubuntu10.15 [84.7 kB]
Get:3 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates/main libc-bin amd64 2.15-0ubuntu10.15 [1,177 kB]
Get:4 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates/main libc6 amd64 2.15-0ubuntu10.15 [4,636 kB]
Fetched 8,840 kB in 0s (34.2 MB/s)
Preconfiguring packages ...
(Reading database ... 72431 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to replace libc6-dev 2.15-0ubuntu10.10 (using .../libc6-dev_2.15-0ubuntu10.15_amd64.deb) ...
Unpacking replacement libc6-dev ...
Preparing to replace libc-dev-bin 2.15-0ubuntu10.10 (using .../libc-dev-bin_2.15-0ubuntu10.15_amd64.deb) ...
Unpacking replacement libc-dev-bin ...
Preparing to replace libc-bin 2.15-0ubuntu10.10 (using .../libc-bin_2.15-0ubuntu10.15_amd64.deb) ...
Unpacking replacement libc-bin ...
Processing triggers for man-db ...
Setting up libc-bin (2.15-0ubuntu10.15) ...
(Reading database ... 72430 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to replace libc6 2.15-0ubuntu10.10 (using .../libc6_2.15-0ubuntu10.15_amd64.deb) ...
Unpacking replacement libc6 ...
Setting up libc6 (2.15-0ubuntu10.15) ...
Setting up libc-dev-bin (2.15-0ubuntu10.15) ...
Setting up libc6-dev (2.15-0ubuntu10.15) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin ...
ldconfig deferred processing now taking place
$ git clone --depth=50 --branch=vincent https://github.com/YangVincent/yelp-and-chill.git YangVincent/yelp-and-chill
Cloning into 'YangVincent/yelp-and-chill'...
remote: Counting objects: 872, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (8/8), done.
remote: Total 872 (delta 3), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 864
Receiving objects: 100% (872/872), 2.51 MiB | 0 bytes/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (119/119), done.
Checking connectivity... done.

$ cd YangVincent/yelp-and-chill
$ git checkout -qf 3508697c5e9c794706d8f20278d4925b86bf9747

This job is running on container-based infrastructure, which does not allow use of 'sudo', setuid and setguid executables.
If you require sudo, add 'sudo: required' to your .travis.yml
See https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/workers/container-based-infrastructure/ for details.

Setting environment variables from repository settings
$ export TWILIO_TOKEN=[secure]
$ export TWILIO_ACCT=[secure]

$ source ~/virtualenv/python3.4/bin/activate

$ python --version
Python 3.4.2
$ pip --version
pip 6.0.7 from /home/travis/virtualenv/python3.4.2/lib/python3.4/site-packages (python 3.4)
$ pip install -r requirements.txt
Collecting pycparser==2.14 (from -r requirements.txt (line 1))
  Downloading pycparser-2.14.tar.gz (223kB)
    100% |################################| 225kB 1.1MB/s 
Collecting requests==2.9.1 (from -r requirements.txt (line 2))
  Downloading requests-2.9.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (501kB)
    100% |################################| 503kB 1.2MB/s 
Collecting simplejson==3.8.2 (from -r requirements.txt (line 3))
  Downloading simplejson-3.8.2.tar.gz (76kB)
    100% |################################| 77kB 6.1MB/s 
Collecting gunicorn==19.6.0 (from -r requirements.txt (line 4))
  Downloading gunicorn-19.6.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (114kB)
    100% |################################| 114kB 4.5MB/s 
Collecting Flask==0.11.1 (from -r requirements.txt (line 5))
  Downloading Flask-0.11.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (80kB)
    100% |################################| 81kB 6.0MB/s 
Collecting twilio==5.4.0 (from -r requirements.txt (line 6))
  Downloading twilio-5.4.0.tar.gz (193kB)
    100% |################################| 196kB 3.0MB/s 
Collecting click>=2.0 (from Flask==0.11.1->-r requirements.txt (line 5))
  Downloading click-6.6.tar.gz (283kB)
    100% |################################| 286kB 2.0MB/s 
Collecting itsdangerous>=0.21 (from Flask==0.11.1->-r requirements.txt (line 5))
  Downloading itsdangerous-0.24.tar.gz (46kB)
    100% |################################| 49kB 8.2MB/s 
Collecting Werkzeug>=0.7 (from Flask==0.11.1->-r requirements.txt (line 5))
  Downloading Werkzeug-0.11.10-py2.py3-none-any.whl (306kB)
    100% |################################| 307kB 2.0MB/s 
Collecting Jinja2>=2.4 (from Flask==0.11.1->-r requirements.txt (line 5))
  Downloading Jinja2-2.8-py2.py3-none-any.whl (263kB)
    100% |################################| 266kB 3.1MB/s 
Collecting httplib2>=0.7 (from twilio==5.4.0->-r requirements.txt (line 6))
  Downloading httplib2-0.9.2.zip (210kB)
    100% |################################| 212kB 1.0MB/s 
Collecting six (from twilio==5.4.0->-r requirements.txt (line 6))
  Downloading six-1.10.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting pytz (from twilio==5.4.0->-r requirements.txt (line 6))
  Downloading pytz-2016.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl (480kB)
    100% |################################| 483kB 1.3MB/s 
Collecting pysocks (from twilio==5.4.0->-r requirements.txt (line 6))
  Downloading PySocks-1.5.7.tar.gz
Collecting MarkupSafe (from Jinja2>=2.4->Flask==0.11.1->-r requirements.txt (line 5))
  Downloading MarkupSafe-0.23.tar.gz
Installing collected packages: MarkupSafe, pysocks, pytz, six, httplib2, Jinja2, Werkzeug, itsdangerous, click, twilio, Flask, gunicorn, simplejson, requests, pycparser
  Running setup.py install for MarkupSafe
    building 'markupsafe._speedups' extension
    gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -g -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -Wformat -Werror=format-security -fPIC -I/opt/python/3.4.2/include/python3.4m -c markupsafe/_speedups.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.4/markupsafe/_speedups.o
    gcc -pthread -shared -L/opt/python/3.4.2/lib -Wl,-rpath=/opt/python/3.4.2/lib build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.4/markupsafe/_speedups.o -L/opt/python/3.4.2/lib -lpython3.4m -o build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/markupsafe/_speedups.cpython-34m.so
  Running setup.py install for pysocks


  Running setup.py install for httplib2


  Running setup.py install for itsdangerous
  Running setup.py install for click
  Running setup.py install for twilio


  Running setup.py install for simplejson
    building 'simplejson._speedups' extension
    gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -g -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -Wformat -Werror=format-security -fPIC -I/opt/python/3.4.2/include/python3.4m -c simplejson/_speedups.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.4/simplejson/_speedups.o
    gcc -pthread -shared -L/opt/python/3.4.2/lib -Wl,-rpath=/opt/python/3.4.2/lib build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.4/simplejson/_speedups.o -L/opt/python/3.4.2/lib -lpython3.4m -o build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/simplejson/_speedups.cpython-34m.so

  Running setup.py install for pycparser
    Build the lexing/parsing tables
Successfully installed Flask-0.11.1 Jinja2-2.8 MarkupSafe-0.23 Werkzeug-0.11.10 click-6.6 gunicorn-19.6.0 httplib2-0.9.2 itsdangerous-0.24 pycparser-2.14 pysocks-1.5.7 pytz-2016.4 requests-2.9.1 simplejson-3.8.2 six-1.10.0 twilio-5.4.0

$ nosetests --with-doctest
.E
======================================================================
ERROR: Failure: NameError (name 'TWILIO_ACCT' is not defined)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/travis/virtualenv/python3.4.2/lib/python3.4/site-packages/nose/failure.py", line 39, in runTest
    raise self.exc_val.with_traceback(self.tb)
  File "/home/travis/virtualenv/python3.4.2/lib/python3.4/site-packages/nose/loader.py", line 414, in loadTestsFromName
    addr.filename, addr.module)
  File "/home/travis/virtualenv/python3.4.2/lib/python3.4/site-packages/nose/importer.py", line 47, in importFromPath
    return self.importFromDir(dir_path, fqname)
  File "/home/travis/virtualenv/python3.4.2/lib/python3.4/site-packages/nose/importer.py", line 94, in importFromDir
    mod = load_module(part_fqname, fh, filename, desc)
  File "/home/travis/virtualenv/python3.4.2/lib/python3.4/imp.py", line 235, in load_module
    return load_source(name, filename, file)
  File "/home/travis/virtualenv/python3.4.2/lib/python3.4/imp.py", line 171, in load_source
    module = methods.load()
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1220, in load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1200, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1129, in _exec
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1471, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 321, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/home/travis/build/YangVincent/yelp-and-chill/text.py", line 4, in <module>
    account_sid = TWILIO_ACCT
NameError: name 'TWILIO_ACCT' is not defined

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 2 tests in 0.200s

FAILED (errors=1)


The command "nosetests --with-doctest" exited with 1.

Done. Your build exited with 1.
```

Answer (score 0):

Although I didn't figure out why, I found what was wrong. First, I decided to store the API keys through the UI. Second, I wasn't using the variables as bash environment variables. Rather, I was using heroku's suggestion of having a .env file.